# Authenticate generated JWT with CookieClient

Tags: jwt, pac4j, javalin

I'm using:
javalin: 5.6.3
javalin-pac4j 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT
pac4j-http, pac4j-jwt, pac4j-core: 6.0.0-RC10

and I want to authenticate a JWT from cookie. I have this configuration:

```
// First I generate JWT token in /form0 and store it to browser cookies ==>

    app.before("/form0", new SecurityHandler(fbpconfig, "CustomFormClient"));
    app.get("/form0", ctx -> protectedPage0(ctx, config));


    private static void protectedPage0(Context ctx, Config config) {

       // Generate and return a JWT
       ProfileManager manager = new ProfileManager(new JEEContext(ctx.req(), ctx.res()), new JEESessionStore());
       Optional<CommonProfile> profile = manager.getProfile(CommonProfile.class);
       String token = "";
       if (profile.isPresent()) {
         JwtGenerator generator = new JwtGenerator();
         token = generator.generate(profile.get());
       }

       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
       model.put("jwtToken", token);

       ctx.render("html/pages/welcome0", model);
   }


    // Setting up a CookieClient, specifying the cookie name and binding default authenticator to validate the token
    CookieClient cookieClient = new CookieClient("jwtToken", new JwtAuthenticator());

    Clients clients = new Clients("http://localhost:7070/welcome",
      cookieClient
    );

    Config config = new Config(clients);


    // Setting up the CookieClient to protected /form1 url
    app.before("/form1", new SecurityHandler(config, "CookieClient"));
    app.get("/form1", ctx -> protectedPage1(ctx, config));
```

This doesn't trigger the JWTAuthenticator, so the JWT isn't validated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Note:
Using HeaderClient and calling /form1 from PostMan with setup Authorization/Bearer/token, works fine. HeaderClient is triggered and token is validated (validateToken() is called)

Answer (score 0):

This looks good. What do you see when debugging in the `CookieExtractor` component?

Comment: Hi jleleu, unfortunately debugger doesn't reach CookieExtractor, CookieClient, JWTAuthorizer. I've added breakpoints with no result.

Comment: Update: I removed pac4j-http from my local maven repo, and seems to get triggered.
But only if I don't first authenticate(JWT) with /form0.

Is there any caching involved?

Comment: UI authentication ("indirect client") is saved into the web session while API authentication ("direct client") is saved into the HTTP request. In both cases, they read the existing authentication from the web session if it exists. So it depends on what you do in /form0.

Comment: I've added /form0 code in description.
I guess web session provides the authentication, and thus CookieClient'JWTAuthenticator isn't triggered?

So, the question is I guess how to indeed authenticate the JWT?

Comment: After generating the JWT, you may remove the pac4j authentication using: `manager.removeProfiles()`.